# local variable 'servers' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
def websvc(currency):
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "aqw", "PFE_Project")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM myform_composantsserveur"
        
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        currency_in = currency
        req = urllib2.urlopen('http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=%s') % (currency_in) 
        req1 = req.read()
        rate = int(req1['rate'])
        # rate = 0.77112893299999996
        
        servers = []
        for row in results:
            result = {} 
            result['1'] = row[1]
            result['3'] = int(row[2])
            result['4'] = int(row[3])
            result['5'] = int(row[4])
            result['6'] = row[5]
            result['7'] = int(row[6])
            result['8'] = row[7]
            result['9'] = row[8]
            p = rate * calculations_metric (int(row[2]), int(row[3]), int(row[4]), int(row[6]), row[7])
            result['2'] = p
            keys = result.keys()
            keys.sort()
            servers.append(result)
             
    except:
        print "Error: unable to fetch data"
    db.close()
    return servers
```

but i have this error while compiling the code :

> Exception Type:   UnboundLocalError
>
> Exception Value:   local variable
> 'servers' referenced before assignment
>
> Exception Location:   /home/amine/PFE Directory/mysite1/myform/Webservice.py in websvc, line 43 Python Executable:    /usr/bin/python2.7

this code works normally before i added a parameter in this function

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Add full error as well as func code with line mentioned in that error

Comment: lasy line "return servers"

Comment: Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value: 
local variable 'servers' referenced before assignment
Exception Location: /home/amine/PFE Directory/mysite1/myform/Webservice.py in websvc, line 43
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python2.7

Comment: And what is in line 43? what code?

Comment: line 43 : return servers

Comment: Ok can you somehow put all your function code inside of question with your indentation to be sure where the error is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code not able to reach servers initialization and that is why you getting error. Simply move initialization before try..except. Change this way:

```
def websvc(currency):
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "aqw", "PFE_Project")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM myform_composantsserveur"
    servers = []

    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        currency_in = currency
        req = urllib2.urlopen('http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=%s') % (currency_in) 
        req1 = req.read()
        rate = int(req1['rate'])
        # rate = 0.77112893299999996

        for row in results:
            result = {} 
            result['1'] = row[1]
            result['3'] = int(row[2])
            result['4'] = int(row[3])
            result['5'] = int(row[4])
            result['6'] = row[5]
            result['7'] = int(row[6])
            result['8'] = row[7]
            result['9'] = row[8]
            p = rate * calculations_metric (int(row[2]), int(row[3]), int(row[4]), int(row[6]), row[7])
            result['2'] = p
            keys = result.keys()
            keys.sort()
            servers.append(result)

    except:
        print "Error: unable to fetch data"
    db.close()
    return servers
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem now you have edited it to add the missing parts. It's the exception handler.

If you have an error after `try` and before `servers=[]` it will jump to the except clause, then see `return servers` and fail.

You might want to use a `list()`, instead of using a `dict()` to emulate a list ...

Answer (score 0):

You can make the empty variable also in the try block if you check against the `globals()` variables any time after the try block. This is no game changer in this code since making a new empty list will never fail, but I could use it to have the opening of a connection into the `try` block so that it would be caught in the exception, and I could close that object in the `finally` block without having to make an empty object before the `try/except/finally` block (tested).

```
def websvc(currency):
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "aqw", "PFE_Project")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM myform_composantsserveur"

    try:
        servers = []
        cursor.execute(sql)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        currency_in = currency
        req = urllib2.urlopen('http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=%s') % (currency_in) 
        req1 = req.read()
        rate = int(req1['rate'])
        # rate = 0.77112893299999996

        for row in results:
            result = {} 
            result['1'] = row[1]
            result['3'] = int(row[2])
            result['4'] = int(row[3])
            result['5'] = int(row[4])
            result['6'] = row[5]
            result['7'] = int(row[6])
            result['8'] = row[7]
            result['9'] = row[8]
            p = rate * calculations_metric (int(row[2]), int(row[3]), int(row[4]), int(row[6]), row[7])
            result['2'] = p
            keys = result.keys()
            keys.sort()
            servers.append(result)

    except:
        print "Error: unable to fetch data"
    db.close()

    if 'servers' in globals():
        return servers 
    else: 
        return []
```

This is untested. If it crashes at `servers.append(result)`, try `if 'servers' in globals():` right before that as well. Which would blow up the code of the `try` block, therefore, I hope that it is not needed, and in my example, I also did not have to do that when I used the called connection afterwards in the `try` block.

Side remark: `append()` makes a full copy. Try `servers.extend([result])` instead if you grow a large list (not likely if you just count up just a few  servers).